# SQL need to apply a variable rate if values occur over consecutive time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have a table that looks like this:

Within the query I need to find the Maximum Import value that occurs over two time periods (rows) where the value is greater that a defined Threshold and apply a rate. If it happens over more than two time periods a different rate will be used

```
Threshold = 1000 
Rate 1 (2 consecutive) = 100
Rate 2 (> 2 consecutive) = 200

Id    DateTime            Import       Export Total
1     2016-01-13 00:00    1000         500    1500
2     2016-01-13 00:15    2500         100    3000
3     2016-01-13 00:30    1900         200    2100
4     2016-01-13 01:00    900          100    1200
```

Ids 2 and 3 are > Threshold so the query should return the MIN value of those (2500,1900) = 1900 minus the Threshold (1000) = 900.  Apply the rate Rate1 * 900 = 9000

If we change the value of Id 4 to 1200 then the MIN value would be 1200.  Less the threshold = 200.  200 * Rate2 = 4000

### Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update after feedback.  My challenge appears to be that I'm not grabbing the 2nd highest value.  Here is an example of the dataset:
[Dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j39xd.png)

I added another var to shrink the list down to test gap and island portion.  Here is a smaller subset:
[Subset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Bxf.png)

Here is the code:

```
    WITH CTE AS (  

SELECT LogTable.[LocalTimestamp] as thetime,LogTable.[SystemImport] as import, LogTable.[Id] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LogTable.[Id]) AS grp
  FROM {System_KWLogRaw} LogTable
  WHERE LogTable.[SystemImport] between @DemandThreshold and @In1 and 
    DATEPART(year,@inDate) = DATEPART(year, LogTable.[LocalTimestamp]) and
    DATEPART(month,@inDate) = DATEPART(month, LogTable.[LocalTimestamp]) and
    DATEPART(day,@inDate) = DATEPART(day, LogTable.[LocalTimestamp])
),

counted AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS cnt
    FROM CTE

    )

SELECT MAX(counted.import) as again1
FROM counted
WHERE cnt > 3 and counted.import < (SELECT MAX(counted.import) FROM counted)
```

This returns 3555.53 instead of 3543.2 which is the 2nd highest value

Comment: What would the results be given your sample data? I assume `9000` and `4000` isn't the full result set you're looking for. Also, what RDBMS are you using? The syntax is different from server to server.

Comment: Hi Rabbit!  I'm using SQL 2012.  The results would be a value (either 9000 or 4000) in this case dependent on if the number of consecutive records is   either = 2 (rate_1) or greater than 2 (rate_2).  My example is misleading it appears.  Imagine the dataset is rather large - by using my original logic I would be missing the answer.  What is needed is the MIN of the top 2 values (in the case of the consecutive=2) or the Top X values (in the case of consecutive>2.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I added the RDBMS to the question. But the rest of your comment is a repeat of your question. It sounds like you want to run a query and the only thing the query returns is a single number. But that doesn't sound very useful to me. There's no supporting information at all. Let's say you have a million records. You want to run a query and the result of the query is 50000. Is that really all you want?

Comment: Also, your results above are incorrect. 900 * Rate1(100) = 90000, not 9000. Same for the second result.

Comment: If all you really want is a single numeric result. And assuming your id is strictly consecutive like your sample data shows. Then you can do what you want with an island and gaps query combined with windowed functions.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I provided an update below.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're asking for:

```
with x as (
select
t1.Id,
t1.DateTime,
t1.Import,
t1.Export,
t1.Total,
count(t2.Import) over (partition by 1) as [QualifyingImports],
min(t2.Import) over (partition by 1) as [MinQualifyingImport]

from
myTable t1
left join myTable t2 on t2.Import > 1000 and t2.Id = t1.Id

where
t1.DateTime >= '2016-01-13'
and t1.DateTime < dateadd(d, 1,'2016-01-13')

)

select
x.Id,
x.DateTime,
x.Import,
x.Export,
x.Total,
case when x.[QualifyingImports] > 2 then (x.MinQualifyingImport - 1000) * 200 else (x.MinQualifyingImport - 1000) * 100 end as [Rate]
from x
```

I've put together a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfab3/1/0) so you can play around with different values for Id # 4.

I really wanted to make the values of things like threshold and period into `@variables`, but it doesn't appear to be supported inside CTEs so I just had to hard code them.

**EDIT**

Turns out the CTE is overkill, you can shrink it down to this and use `@variables`, yay!

```
declare @period smalldatetime = '2016-01-13'
declare @threshold float = 1000
declare @rate1 float = 100
declare @rate2 float = 200

select
t1.Id,
t1.DateTime,
t1.Import,
t1.Export,
t1.Total,
case
  when count(t2.Import) over (partition by 1) > 2 then (min(t2.Import) over (partition by 1) - @threshold) * @rate2
  else (min(t2.Import) over (partition by 1) - @threshold) * @rate1
  end as [Rate]

from
myTable t1
left join myTable t2 on t2.Import > @threshold and t2.Id = t1.Id

where
t1.DateTime >= @period
and t1.DateTime < dateadd(d, 1, @period)
```

New [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfab3/4/0)

Comment: Hi Joe!  Thank you for the help!  I'm afraid when I put in a new value to test the consecutive part it fails the logic:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8111e/2 The purpose behind this requirement is to allow for rapid ups and downs in the data as long as they don't span a certain number of consecutive time periods.

Comment: Are the values in "Id" incremented in line with the ascending DateTimes? If so, we can use this to emulate a `LEAD` / `LAG` function with another self join.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5ee2/1/0) is what you're going for? It now checks the previous row to see if that one also had an Import value above the threshold and only applies the rate2 in that situation (i.e. the imports over threshold must be consecutive). This results in a changing value in the "Rate" column, so maybe not exactly what you need, but are we getting close?

Comment: Hi Joe! Thanks again!!  The code I posted in the update seems to be working in terms of finding the correct value. The one thing missing is that instead of applying the rate here I have to apply it outside the query, so the query needs to output a value (preferably boolean) that is True if cnt >4  That way I will know what rate to apply down the road